# <style> tag within <template>

Tags: html, html-templates

I was going through the MDN page for [Using Templates and Slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) where it mentions while citing an example of using `<template>` within a Shadow DOM that (emphasis mine):

> And because we are appending its contents to a shadow DOM, we can
> include some styling information inside the template in a 
> element, which is then encapsulated inside the custom element. **This
> wouldn't work if we just appended it to the standard DOM.**

My understanding from this statement is that `<style>` tags within `<template>` work only in a shadow tree but upon trying an example of doing the same and appending the `<template>` to the standard DOM, I see that it works (tried in Chrome, Mozilla, and Safari)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <template id="template">
        <style>
            span {
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <span>Span from template</span>
    </template>
</body>
<script>
    const template = document.getElementById('template');
    const templateContent = template.content;
    document.body.appendChild(templateContent);
</script>
</html>
```

I also thought that it might be referring to appending a standalone `<style>` tag to the standard DOM for which I tried this snippet which too seemed to work fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Test</div>
</body>
<script>
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
     div {
         color: blue;
     }
     `;
     document.body.appendChild(style);
</script>
</html>
```

I'm guessing my inference is incorrect(or are the docs incorrect?). What limitation is that statement actually referring to?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

Comment: @RobertLongson I was coming from those pages. Is it actually referring to `styling information inside the template in a <style> element, which is then encapsulated inside the custom element.` which (obviously) won't work in a standard DOM? The _encapsulation_ is the point, I guess.

Comment: You don't seem to be using shadow DOM at all i.e. there's no calls to attachShadow in your code.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I am not using them in the snippets pasted in the question. My query was more on the lines of what it mentions regarding the limitation. I think your suggestion seems to indicate that they are referring to the _encapsulation of style_ which won't be possible in a Standard DOM but is possible in a shadow DOM. I guess _that_ is the limitation.

Comment: You're right, afaict. Raw templates (forget components) seem like an easy way to encapsulate chunks of UI combined with their own <style> elements. Templates can also be nested (only testing on Chrome), tho you then have to recurse when turning them into DOM nodes. Seems easier than messing with "components" for some applications at least.